# Reverse Display for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Does anyone know of an easy way to switch [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) into a [reverse display](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_video) without having to manually change all the color settings, similar to [Emacs --reverse-video](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_538.html)?
Thanks!
-Max

Addendum: I encountered a few more interesting articles around this topic.  Nothing for Eclipse though.

- [Slashdot: Best Color Scheme For Coding, Easiest On the Eyes?](http://developers.slashdot.org/developers/08/07/03/1249246.shtml)
- [Coding Horror: Is Your IDE Hot or Not?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000682.html)
- [Zenburn for Konsole](http://termos.vemod.net/zenburn-for-konsole)

Comment: what exactly do you mean with reverse? Just make the light parts dark and vice versa or change the colors too like in negative / positive iamges.

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to use [someone else's preferences](http://blog.codefront.net/2006/09/28/vibrant-ink-textmate-theme-for-eclipse/) and import then modify them, I'm not aware of a way other than to manually configure the colours - it would be nice if it shipped with pre-defined themes. (note: I'm still on Europa)

Answer (score 0):

Or: use a window manager that supports that. I use eclipse on linux, wm=compiz

Inversion is always a mere +N (aka. Windows+N) away

Now, I bet there are equivalents in windows (why not?)

Answer (score 0):

Not really but try installing [Eclipse Color Theme](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=plugin) for easy theme editing